# Laravel post request route

Tags: laravel, parameters, controller, routes, arguments

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axT2Z.png)I have a following Controller in php laravel:

```
// .....

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
//...
//...
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

I use the following route:

```
Route::post('api/auth/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@create');
```

I am getting the following error: "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

I need your help to pass Request parameters to my function (Form route properly)

Comment: try `Auth\RegisterController@register` instead of `Auth\RegisterController@create`

Comment: You are sending the data by route parameter or inside the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your method parameter to [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#accessing-the-request) $request

> to obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency
>   injection, you should type-hint the `Illuminate\Http\Request` class on
>   your controller method. The incoming request instance will
>   automatically be injected by the service container

and get the data from the request fields:

```
protected function create(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
}
```

If you do not want to write all the `Request` namespace in the method parameter, add on the top of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

then, just use the name of the class:

```
protected function create(Request $request)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Getting the following error: Class App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\Request does not exist. (use http\Env\Request;)

Comment: add use Illuminate\Http\Request; on the top of the file

Comment: or use` create(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way,

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    protected function create(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```